# how to manage ui in nexus 4 and 6

Tags: android

I am a developer and I am recently facing  a issue that the client want the images and buttons in exact same place in all the android devices such as: Motorola, nexus 4, nexus 6, nexus 5. When i develop the user interface  it changes its position as the device changes. I have 70 user interface screens , I cannot create multiple screens, and Dimensions layout also. I tried with weight and relative layout, constraint layout but the problem is same.

Edit: Images of how it looks on a Nexus 6 emulator and Nexus 4 emulator

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTEpT.jpg

Comment: `in exact same place` relative to what? in pixels to the top left corner?

Comment: please add your code you are using for creating the layout

Comment: Stopped yelling, fixed formatting

Answer (score 0):

So There are two ways to make your app compatible with all devices.

- **Option one**

  You have to create all images(slices) used in your app with compatible of all dimens(mdpi,hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi).

to check out resolutions and size of all devices, you can go here for reference [Device List](https://material.io/devices/).

- **Option two**

  You have to create only xxhdpi images and manage it with dimens of mdpi,hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi (it is not proper way but can help you).

There is good library for all dimens that you can use. [All Dimens Lib](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

Comment: I have used different drawable but the Moto g and Zenfone both comes in xHdpi so when i give margin then the image somewhat get disturb from its place.

Comment: you can differentiate the height of both xhdpi phones by their density.
and using of density you can manage it by code. to get density **try this** `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;`